# Executing Login API in which Authentication process happens with Active Directory

Tags: jmeter, active-directory

I am trying to do the performance testing of a logistics application. 2 types of users are there - Internal users & External Users. For internal users the authentication process happens normally; usual database. I was successful in executing the jmx script for Internal users. But for External users, the authentication process happens with Active Directory. In this case when i tried to execute the jmx script, the user is not getting logged in to the application. But the login api doesn't gives any error, the Response Code is 200 but in Response I'm getting the message "Try again". Do we need to do any additional settings in Jmeter for Active Directory Authentication? Can anybody help me in this?

Answer (score 1):

For "internal" users you might need to add [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) and configure not only username and password but also domain, realm and use appropriate mechanism for [NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager) or [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol))

See [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) article for more detailed explanation and example configurations

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing out on a few key things such as HTTP Headers or some additional data that needs to be sent with the request.

To resolve this. you can analyze the request in the developer tools of your browser and then generate the same headers with the request. This will resolve the issue.

Comment: I have checked the headers and all the items are added

Comment: Did you try using Postman? If it is working on postman then you can replicate the same here as well. It's just that you need to fulfil the criteria that ad demands.